# Azure Container Service container cannot access other port except 80

Tags: magento, docker, containers, bitnami, azure-container-service

I finally figure out how to to install Magento container into Swarm dockers cluster, and now I could access its URL, e.g.  http://xxxagents.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com    (port 80)

Then I got another issue: if I use docker-compose to install another container with Magento port number 83 (non-80), my web browser tells me page cannot be open.

Here is my yml script for that part:

```
magento:
  image: 'bitnami/magento:latest'
  environment:         
    - MAGENTO_HOST=xxxxagents.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
    - MARIADB_HOST=10.0.0.4
    - MARIADB_PORT=3303
    - APACHE_HTTP_PORT=83
ports:
     - '83:83'
```

The host & port number has been successfully written into core_config_data table. Does anyone know why I cannot open via: http://xxxagents.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com:83 ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, I will respect your decision. I had though "scripting" is also part of programming :-) If you want to close, then it's fine.

Comment: BTW mate, are you the same company?

Comment: I haven't made a decision - I just voted to close. This looks like configuration rather than coding. A script can be either. The questions here should be about a programming issue. And what you you mean about "same company"?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, please correct me if I am wrong: When I login to StackOverFlow main dashboard I can see all kinds of IT-related questions, e.g. people ask about photoshop issue, network settings etc. I am always thinking this site is not only for coding related question :-)

Comment: From the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page - "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."

Comment: From the [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page, valid questions must be "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: Understood. Thanks boss!

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the port in the Azure Load Balancer. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access (this is listed as a doc for ACS using DC/OS but the process should be the same)

Comment: That helps! Thanks mate!